# "How do u want to open this file" for run commands

Tags: windows-10

When I run `%temp%` using `Win+R` , I get a popup:

> "How do you want to open this file?"

To prevent the popup, I can encapsulate using double quotation marks: `"%temp%"`.

Why doesn't `%temp%` without quotes work? I think all started after the trial period of application "StartIsBack" ended. Since the trial ended, I can't access the properties of "StartIsBack", as it gives me the same popup message.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and asked a question about it, even though it did not get an answer (so this one should not be flagged as duplicate).

[Running %temp% goes to file in Users folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1312738/running-temp-goes-to-file-in-users-folder)

This is how I fixed it:

There was a space in my non-8.3 user folder (for example, User Name, rather then USERNA~1) that would cause programs to see it as 2 parameters `C:\Users\User` (as 1st parameter) and `Name\AppData\Local\Temp` (as second parameter). It reads the first parameter, causing it to reroute to the file User in the Users folder. Deleting the file `C:\Users\User` solved it (It was not important because it only contained CMD errors).

Now, why did it work in quotes? Because it sees `"User Name"` as 1 parameter, but `User Name` as 2.

You could not access the program "StartIsBack"'s properties because they are likely at `C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\StartIsBack\` (note the space!).

Comment: If that fixed your own question Zackary, feel free to post that as the answer and then mark it as such. Self-answered questions are every bit as good and welcome as questions someone else answers.